Dubbio ignobile: "dire se è" o "dire se sia"?
Ho un dubbio ignobile, e come da titolo sono molto indeciso (forse anche confuso) sulla duplice, o meno, correttezza delle seguenti proposizioni:

Dire se A è un insieme aperto o no.
Dire se A sia un insieme aperto o no.

A sentimento e udito, opterei per la seconda forma, con il congiuntivo. Tuttavia la prima forma non mi suona così errata.
C'è qualche regola che ignoro che vieta la prima o ne consdiera invece la correttezza?

Anche se la seconda forma fosse corretta (ma l'Accademia della Crusca afferma che con il verbo dire va di solito l'indicativo https://accademiadellacrusca.it/it/consulenza/uso-del-congiuntivo/104) non la userei mai, non si usa, mi sembrerebbe di fare la figura di Fantozzi che usa il congiuntivo quando gioca a tennis con Filini :-).

@BakerStreet haha ti ringrazio per la risposta, il link e l'aneddoto :) E dire che a me sembrava più naturale... Pensa te. Grazie!

Mi fa piacere che conosci Fantozzi, temevo che caso mai non fossi italiano e ti confondevo le idee!

@BakerStreet: L'articolo dell'Accademia della Crusca penso si riferisca a costrutti del tipo "dire che". Le frasi della domanda sono, secondo me, interrogative indirette.

@Charo Non ho discusso la questione dal punto di vista grammaticale, ho detto che è una costruzione che anche se corretta non avrei mai usato, perché comunque goffa, uno stile faticoso, brutto, un italiano a mio parere fintamente colto (da cui il riferimento a Fantozzi..) che oltretutto non ho mai visto usare in un contesto di matematica come quello (di matematica ne ho letta). Poi ognuno sceglie il suo stile.

@BakerStreet Grazie per aver sottolineato che di Matematica ne hai letta tanta. Mi sto interfacciando con varie realtà (persone, professori, libri) dove ho visto entrambe le forme e mi sono veramente chiesto "qual è la forma corretta / migliore"? Da lì, la necessità di chiedere :)

Grammaticalmente non so di preciso, quell'imperativo davanti ,'dire', mi dà dubbi. Uno direbbe a una persona: "Verifica se il gatto di Maria sia nero o bianco"? È un italiano decente? Non mi pare  nemmeno una interrogativa. Ma non so.

@Henry Per qualche altro esempio tratto dalla matematica, se ad esempio uno vedesse scritto: "Verificare se la funzione f sia derivabile" oppure "Verificare se il seguente limite esista" , risulterebbe parecchio strano.

Io userei  "Verificare se il seguente limite esista"  tranquillamente.

Anche a me il congiuntivo stona parecchio. Per capire meglio (anche qui, persona non ignara di matematica), qual è il contesto? È il testo di un esercizio?

@DaG Sì, stavo scrivendo il testo e per la prima volta mi sono soffermato a pensare davvero alla forma di questa frase rendendomi conto che ho visto entrambe nel tempo, in libri e altri files. Mi ha proprio preso il dubbio enorme al punto di dover chiedere haha. Il testo dell'esercizio è qualcosa del tipo: "Si consideri (alternativa: data la funzion...) la funzione F (o l'insieme, a seconda della scelta) bla bla. Dire se F sia/è derivabile in x = 0 oppure no // dire se l'insieme A sia/è chiuso oppure no.
